# Does list comprehension work with insert()? Or is it limited to append() only?

Tags: python, list, insert, list-comprehension

The code here I want to use list comprehension, its for this:

output=[[],[]]

it should come out as [[],' ',[]]

```py
for i in range(len(output)):
    if i%2==0:
        output.insert(i+1, ' ')
print(output)
```

full code:

```py
#Practice of List/array and string 
# There is an sentence in reverse order can you make it right using python code
string =['p','e','r','f','e','c','t',' ','m','a','k','e','s',' ','p','r','a','c','t','i','c','e']
#step 1
part=[list(item) for item in ''.join(string).split(' ')]#list comprehension
#step 2
for i in range(len(part)):
    if i%2==0:
        part.insert(i+1, ' ')
#step 3
part.reverse()
#step 4
res=[item for elem in part for item in elem]
print(res)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I get what you seem to be saying is your desired output. Do you get something different?

Comment: It's for a school project. i don't get anything different i was curious if i can implement with list comprehension

Comment: can you describe what you are trying to accomplish? List comprehensions perform mapping/filtering operations on iterables to yield a new list.

Comment: I just wanted my code to be efficient

Comment: Your code always seems to be inserting at the end, which is the same as appending.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the same with a list comprehension:

```
output = [[] if j % 2 == 0 else ' ' for j in range(3)]
``
```